# Php get the value from a particular node in XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml response which has the following nodes in it

```
$response = '<packet version="1.6.6.0">
  <webspace>
    <del>
      <result>
        <status>ok</status>
        <filter-id>14</filter-id>
        <id>14</id>
      </result>
    </del>
  </webspace>
</packet>';
```

I want to grab the value of the node `<filter-id>` in a variable.

I am doing the following,

```
$dbres = simplexml_load_string($response);
$filterid = $dbres->webspace->result->filter-id;
echo $filterid;
```

I am getting error `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` which I think indicated the hyphen "-" in `filter-id`. I cannot change the xml as it is a response from API. How can I get the filter-id ?

Comment: Try this $dbres->webspace->result->{'filter-id'};

Comment: Let me try that.. I will post you in a moment.

Comment: @Samir, your solution is working for me.. But you did not create an answer for that. If you create an answer I will be happy to accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$dbres->webspace->result->{'filter-id'};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use brackets:

```
$dbres = simplexml_load_string($response);
$filterid = $dbres->webspace->result->{filter-id};
echo $filterid;
```

Or cast it:

```
$dbres = simplexml_load_string($response);
$filterid = ((array) $dbres->webspace->result)['filter-id'];
echo $filterid;
```

Or - a bit weird:

```
$dbres = simplexml_load_string(str_replace("filter-id", "filterid", $response));
$filterid = $dbres->webspace->result->filterid;
echo $filterid;
```

Comment: @Illusion: You can vote up my answer and mark it as solution if you want so.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as I have already marked Sameers answer.